# Failure to display DataTable in RShiny App

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

I'm hoping to display a reactive datatable for my Shiny app. I'm using `renderDataTable()` and have made sure that the data table is returned in the reactive function. I've noticed that the datatable renders fine outside of the Shiny App, so not a variable/computation error. The reason I'm hoping to use a datatable in the first place is so that I can display cleaned up column names and display the dataframe in a more clean manner. Please let me know what else I can try, or if I should change my approach.

Here is the server code:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  dataset <- reactive({
    shiny_tuition_salary <- datatable(df_tuition_salary %>%
                                        select(name, mean_net_cost, state) %>%
                                        filter(mean_net_cost >= input$input_budget[1],
                                               mean_net_cost <= input$input_budget[2],
                                               state == input$input_state) %>%
                                        select(name, mean_net_cost))

    return(shiny_tuition_salary)
  })

  output$df <- renderDataTable({

    dataset()

  })

}
```

Currently nothing is displayed under the Table tab in the app. The app also successfully displays the table when DataTable is not used at all (i.e. removing `datatable()` from the server and using RenderTable instead of RenderDataTable), so I'm positive there's an issue with my implementation of `RenderDataTable()`

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's the `ui` code and a sample `df_tuition_salary` as well

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("What colleges match your budget and rank?"),

  # Sidebar laayout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Slider for the number of bins ----
      sliderInput(inputId = "input_budget",
                  label = "Budget:",
                  min = 0,
                  max = 50000,
                  value = c(0, 15000)),
      selectInput(inputId = "input_state",
                  label = "State (limited data, may limit options):",
                  choices = df_tuition_salary$state)

    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id = 'output_df',
        # tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot")),
        tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("df"))
      )

    )
  )
)
```

df_tuition_salary:

```
df_tuition_salary <- data.frame(name = c("Aaniiih Nakoda College", "Abilene Christian University"),
           mean_net_cost = c(7508.2414, 24884.0828),
           state = c("N/A", "N/A"))
```

Comment: just added to the post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `dataTableOutput()` function.

```
# Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id = 'output_df',
        # tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot")),
        tabPanel("Table", dataTableOutput("df"))
      )
```

Comment: Please mark the solution for the benefit of those to follow.